# Excel - Show only/all columns with substring in column header

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table

I'd like to sort my data by column substring but I don't know how to do it. I've tried pivot tables but had no success and I know how to use the LEFT function to find a starting substring but I can't figure out how to filter all other columns out.

I'm trying to sort my grades by assignment type and then make calculations on that subset of data. The first column is the student's username and then all other columns contain pass/fail data for each assignment. There are three different types of assignments PQ, RQ , and WQ (proficiency quiz, reading quiz, and weekly quiz), so each column's header starts with either PQ, RQ, or WQ. I'd like to make a table (or new sheet) that shows all/only PQ columns for example. This also needs to happen dynamically so that if add more PQs throughout the semester the table will reflect that when I refresh it so I don't want to hard-code it.

Here is an image of my sample data:

```
+----------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
| Username | PQ1  | PQ2  | RQ2  | PQ3  | WQ1  | RQ2  | PQ4  | RQ3  | PQ5  | WQ2  |
+----------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
| Bill123  | Pass | Pass | Pass | Pass | Fail | Pass | Pass | Pass | Pass | Pass |
+----------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
| Mike4    | Pass | Pass | Pass | Pass | Pass | Pass | Pass | Pass | Pass | Pass |
+----------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
| LeslieXY | Pass | Pass | Pass | Pass | Pass | Pass | Pass | Pass | Pass | Pass |
+----------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
| Alex1    | Pass | Fail | Pass | Pass | Pass | Pass | Pass | Pass | Pass | Fail |
+----------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
| Alex2    | Pass | Fail | Pass | Pass | Pass | Pass | Pass | Pass | Pass | Pass |
+----------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
| SarahB4  | Fail | Pass | Fail | Fail | Pass | Pass | Fail | Pass | Pass | Fail |
+----------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
```

[(Color Image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ou9ex.jpg)

Here are the sorts of subsets I'd like to see in a new sheet or table:

```
+----------+------+------+------+------+------+
| Username | PQ1  | PQ2  | PQ3  | PQ4  | PQ5  |
+----------+------+------+------+------+------+
| Bill123  | Pass | Pass | Pass | Pass | Pass |
+----------+------+------+------+------+------+
| Mike4    | Pass | Pass | Pass | Pass | Pass |
+----------+------+------+------+------+------+
| LeslieXY | Pass | Pass | Pass | Pass | Pass |
+----------+------+------+------+------+------+
| Alex1    | Pass | Fail | Pass | Pass | Pass |
+----------+------+------+------+------+------+
| Alex2    | Pass | Fail | Pass | Pass | Pass |
+----------+------+------+------+------+------+
| SarahB4  | Fail | Pass | Fail | Fail | Pass |
+----------+------+------+------+------+------+
```

[Color Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9r2s3.jpg)

Thanks for any help you can offer!!

Answer (score 1):

**You need to follow these steps:**

[image]

**How it works:**

- Select data range `J40:O42`.
- From **Home Tab** click **Sort & Filter.**
- Hit **Custom Sort.**
- From the appeared dialogue click **Option** button.
- Set Option **Sort Left to Right**, finish with **Ok.**
- Then from **Row Sort by** select the Header Row (in this example is `Row 40`), finish with **Ok.**

[image]

- *You get data in New Order.*

[image]

*Adjust cell references as needed.*